# How to get new mongoid indexes for a model

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have defined my model Person with a couple of indexes:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email
  field :ssn

  index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })
  index({ ssn: 1 }, { unique: true })
end
```

However, only the email index already exists in the database, so when I call

```
Person.collection.indexes.each {|i| puts i.inspect}
```

I get the following response:

```
{"v"=>1, "key"=>{"_id"=>1}, "name"=>"_id_", "ns"=>"x.person"}
{"v"=>1, "unique"=>true, "key"=>{"email"=>1}, "name"=>"email_1", "ns"=>"x.person"}
```

The question is, how can I get the list of defined indexes in the model, even if they are not already created in mongo ?

In my case, such list should include the definition for the field "ssn"

In other words...How to get those indexes that haven't been created yet ?

Answer (score 7):

```
Person.index_specifications
```

shows the indexes defined in the model regardless of its existence in the database.

And

```
Person.collection.indexes
```

only shows the index that actually exists in the database.

So there is something else that is worth paying attention to:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

will create the indexes defined in the model in the database, and it uses the method 'index_specifications' in deed.

While this removes all the indexes other than the index of the primary key:

```
rake db:mongoid:remove_indexes
```

So when you want to only remove the indexes that exists in the database but no longer defined in the database, you should use this:

```
rake db:mongoid:remove_undefined_indexes
```

which use the method 'undefined_indexes' in deed.

I hope this can be helpful.

The docs are here:

https://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Tasks/Database#create_indexes-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

Just found it...

We can get the list of all index definitions into the model as follows:

```
Person.index_specifications
```

This is an array populated when the application is loaded and is used by the "create_indexes" method as can be seen here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/indexable.rb